# Grpc.Core.Xamarin giving object file was built for newer iOS Simulator version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grpc

I am trying to build a gRPC client for mobile using Xamarin.Forms and Grpc.Core and Grpc.Core.Xamarin. Everything is currently working for Android, however my iOS project will not build. I get a little over 100 errors (and 1000 warnings) stating "warning: object file (C:/Users/Matt/.nuget/packages/grpc.core.xamarin/2.41.1/build/Xamarin.iOS10/../../native/ios/universal/libgrpc.a(server_address.o)) was built for newer iOS Simulator version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)"

Now the iOS .csproj file does indeed show the version of my simulator is 8

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">iPhoneSimulator</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{AA8D5164-21F8-4A44-96F9-A8D3E0021486}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{89a4fe7c-635d-49c9-8d8c-5cd363c0d68d}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>myProject.iOS</RootNamespace>
    <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
    <AssemblyName>myProject.iOS</AssemblyName>
    <MtouchEnableSGenConc>true</MtouchEnableSGenConc>
    <MtouchHttpClientHandler>NSUrlSessionHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
    <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see above the version is 8.0.30703. I cannot however seem to find any information on how to update my simulator to version 9.0.

Any and all help is appreciated, I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: Check your Info.plist

Comment: God thank you. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Cahyo mentioned, the solution was in my info.plist file. Just needed to change my deployment target from 8.0 to 9.0 or above.